# Inequality in products of probability measures

Tags: measure-theory, game-theory

For each $i=1,\ldots,N$ let $X_i$ be a compact subset of a t.v.s Hausdorff.
Let $M_i$ be the set of regular probability measures on $X_i$ and $u_i: \prod X_i \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a measurable bounded function.

If $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_N) \in \prod M_i$ , there exists a $\tilde{x}_i \in X_i$ such that 
$$ \int_{X_{-i}}u_i(\tilde{x}_i,y)d\lambda_{-i}(y) \geq \int_{X}u_i(x,y)d\lambda_i(x)d\lambda_{-i}(y)  $$

Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: What are $X_{-i}$ and $\lambda_{-i}$?

Comment: I'm sorry. $X_{-i}= \prod_{j\neq i} X_j$ and $\lambda_{-i} = \otimes_{j\neq i}\lambda_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If the inequality is false for every $\tilde {x_i}$ just integrate w.r.t. $\lambda_i$ to get a contradiction.

Comment: I'm sorry, I dont not understand well. If I integrate the inequality wrt $\lambda_i$ I form an equality.

Comment: If $f(x)<a$ for all $x$ and $\mu$ is a probability measure then $\int f(x)d\mu(x) <c$. So if we know that $\int f(x)d\mu(x) =c$ then we have a contradiction. So it is the equality you have quoted which leads to a  contradiction.

Comment: You're right, I was considering non-strict inequality. Thanks a lot!